# Scikit-Learn ElasticNetCV gives different "best" alpha values using the same random state with `n_jobs` set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I was using [ElasticNetCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV) method in `sklearn`. I used the following code, trying to see if I can replicate the "best" alpha selected by cross validation but got different estimates if I run the same code for multiple times:

```
reg = ElasticNetCV(cv=5, random_state=1000, n_jobs=20, max_iter=10000,
                   alphas=pd.np.linspace(0.01, .99, 100), l1_ratio=0.2)
reg.fit(X, Y_number)
print(reg.alpha_)
```

For example, sometimes I got 0.04, sometimes I got 0.99. However, if I remove `n_jobs`, the result seems to be stable. Is there a reason why `n_jobs` will introduce the instability of results?

Comment: It should not be affected by the `n_jobs`. What do you mean by stable when not using the `n_jobs`? Do you mean that they are along the same numbers (in close proximity)?

Comment: @VivekKumar I mean if I remove the argument `n_jobs` in the constructor function call of elastic net.

Comment: @Zhiya have you tried different values for the random state e.g. random_state = 1, to see what happens ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `random_state=1` and `random_state=0`. I got more 0.99 for `alpha` but that can still change (for example, to 0.06) after some more tries.

Comment: May I please ask you why you need to set n_jobs? According to ElasticNetCV documentation,  n_jobs is the number of CPUs to use during the cross validation.